# Windows AWS EC2 Instance User Data PowerShell do not load Powershell Modules for System Account level

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2

I have created a PowerShell script to run in the user data of an AWS Windows instance. If I manually execute the script as Administrator, it runs successfully and does work.

[image: User Data Script]

But when I send the script in user data (during instance creation) it throws an exception. This happens during the installation of the module from System Account

PowerShell Version on EC2 Windows 2012 R2  =  v4.0

```
 Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
 

2017-04-10T18:24:25.004Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: Executing C:Windowssystem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted . 'C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Scripts\UserScript.ps1' from System account
2017-04-10T18:24:25.006Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: Executing User Data with PID: 1084
2017-04-10T18:24:34.639Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: ExitCode of User Data with PID: 1084 is 1
2017-04-10T18:24:34.642Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: The errors from user scripts: iex : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At C: Program Files Amazon Ec2ConfigService Scripts UserScript.ps1:5 char:79
+  (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") 
| ie ...
+                                                                              
 ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterB 
   indingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl 
   lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
 

2017-04-10T18:24:34.642Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: The output from user scripts: 
2017-04-10T18:24:34.642Z: Background plugin complete: Ec2HandleUserData
```

**Work Around /Solution** : This is more of PsGet Module issue, not EC2 issue

https://github.com/psget/psget/issues/208

At System Account level PsGet Module was setting Path InCorrectly.
As of now I have Modified PsGet.ps1 to read my custom path $env:PSModulePath, and it works with no issues.

PsGet.Ps1 Line 1615
Comment the line #Add-PathToPSModulePath -PathToAdd:$Destination -PersistEnvironment:$PersistEnvironment -Global:$Global

Added : [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", ";C:{DirectoryIwantModulesToBe}\Modules", "Machine")

It works , at System Account level with no Issues

Thanks Alex for help.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with PsGet when System User calls install-modules on powershell - https://github.com/psget/psget/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use specific paths. The userdata block executes under the windows system account and as such it doesn't have a profile directory nor a temp path.
For example `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()` fails when executing with this user.

This is the same when code-deploy packages execute.

If you have to work often with AWS-EC2 then it's best to try to replicate the environment as much as possible locally because an EC2 takes minimum 6 minutes to launch and that can be a major slow down in your troubleshooting efforts. For this reason, I've decided to setup a vagrant box with the matching operating system and on that box I execute/test what I need. When things get tough and I'm suspicious of the System user's special characteristics, I use psexec to launch my processes. This is a good starting point [How to: become the LOCAL SYSTEM account with PsExec](https://specopssoft.com/how-to-become-the-local-system-account-with-psexec/)

Comment: Thanks Alex, this helps to debug the issue. I do use https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/ On same instance to replicate.

Comment: You mentioned about using specific paths.  Tried Setting New Module Path & new directory 
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",";C:\Modules", "Machine")
Still Get Exception , when I try to install Modules

Comment: I mean download the file to specific folders. `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $outFilePath` where `$outFilePath` is for example on `C:\` but not on the temp folder. Then execute the downloaded artifact on `$outFilePath`.

Comment: Also, please notice that `$env:PSModulePath` contains one entry that is inside the user profile. That appears strangely truncated to `\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Comment: I haven't tried to install the **PowerShellGet** from the userdata. I actually build amis using packer and I installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 using a provisioning script. In this [packer file](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/packer-ami/Source/Packer/mssql2014-ish-amazon-ebs.json) notice the line `& C:/Provision/ISHBootstrap/Source/Server/PackageManagement/Install-PackageManagement.ps1`. It is the one that installs PackageManagement on the server.

Comment: Check out also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Sarafian/ed7ec82e1aef12f77661b81cf8b9361d) to help you launch processes as the System user.

Comment: Thank you Alex, At System Account level PsGet Module was setting Path InCorrectly, as of now I have Modified PsGet.ps1 to read my custom path $env:PSModulePath, and it works with no issues  

PsGet.Ps1 Line 1615 Add-PathToPSModulePath -PathToAdd:$Destination -PersistEnvironment:$PersistEnvironment -Global:$Global

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", ";C:{DirectoryIwantModulesToBe}\Modules", "Machine") and it works , at System Account level with no Issues.

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote for my answer and I advice to edit your original post with the code you just provided and mention the how you got there. Comments are not friendly with multi-line code unfortunately.